# A suitable word for a child being not well-aware

Tags: vocabulary

What is the right word for a child who is not well-aware of things like an adult usually is; that is, his level of sensing/understanding things (being right or wrong) is not the same that of an adult.

1. Unsenible
2. Insensible
3. Inadvisable
4. Unwise
5. Naive

**Unsenible**: I think it is not a word that we find in a standard dictionary.

**Insensible**: means ‘ unconscious’.

**Inadvisable**: we use it to talk about things like 'idea' but I'm not sure if we can use it to describe a person e.g. he is an inadvisable child.

**Unwise**: this sounds rude.

**Naive**: ?

Comment: Are these alternatives supplied for a grammar exercise? Your comments on the first three are correct. There is no such word as _unsenible_. _Unwise_ normally describes a foolish action by someone who _ought_ to know better. _Naïve_ would do for a child - you could also say _inexperienced, immature_ or _unworldly_.

Comment: No, it's for academic writing.